# collection of items which makes the fields of the items as collection accessible

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I don't know if this is possible, and how it would be possible. I basicly want to use  this later that like:

```
//setting a single item as known.
label1.BackColor=Color.FromARGB(255,255,255);
/*setting multiple items in something like a container (wanted, not yet possible)*/
sContainer.BackColor=Color.FromARGB(255,255,255);
//and that's how it works recently with my class...
sContainer.SetValues("BackColor",Color.FromARGB(255,255,255));
```

The container will have to use Generics and Reflection I guess. 
The container class should "copy" all Set-able properties of the T-Class (here Control) into itself. So if I'm using `SetContainer<Control>` I can set all backcolor values in my container by `sContainer1.BackColor=...` .

My code until know looks that like:

```
public class SetContainer<T>:IList<T>
{
/*I've implemented all methods of IList by using the elements-List*/
private List<T> elements;
public void SetValues(string propname,object value)
    {
     FieldInfo f=typeof(T).GetField(propname);
     elements.ForEach(x=>f.SetField(x,value);
    }
}
```

I'm sorry that I don't know how to describe this well understandable.

Comment: What kind of object is sContainer? Do you know the potential properties beforehand?

Comment: sContainer is recently an instance of my class (second snippet). But recently `sContainer.BackColor` isn't usable(but I want to use this way because of more typo-safety ...).. recently only `sContainer.SetValues `  is working.

Comment: Why doesn't that piece of code work? In any case setting Control properties can have side effects. I think you should drop this approach.

Comment: well, I don't want to use always a loop to apply a value to every element of an collection, so I want to access it at the collection level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using this a modified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521682/expandoobject-add-property-with-extra-code/32522785#32522785), you can add "link" the properties of the generic class to the container class.

This makes it possible to apply one value to a whole collection of values.

Thank you @Sagi !